How to make numbers that are always in sequence with postgresql or prisma?



code
number
description




A123
1
.......................


A123
2
.......................


A123
3
.......................



I have a table in PostgreSQL with code A123, and column "number" with sequence, if i remove row with "number" value 2, the result is :



code
number
description




A123
1
...............


A123
3
...............



How to get the numbers back in order with postgresql or prisma ?
expected : numbers value become 1 & 2 :



code
number
description




A123
1
.......................


A123
2
.......................




Use a view with a window function that hides that column and replaces it with row_number()over(order by "number"). If you need the table to be saved like that, use a trigger that does the same but uses it to overwrite the column.

It's also worth mentioning why you think you need that
